# How many SQL queries can be run at a time?

Tags: iphone, python, mysql, objective-c, database

I am looking to store information in a database table that will be constantly receiving and sending data back and forth to an iPhone App/Python Socket. The problem is, if I were to have my own servers, what is the maximum queries I can sustain?

The reason I'm asking is because if I were to have thousands of people using the clients and multiple queries are going a second, I'm afraid something will go wrong.

Is there a different way of storing user information without MySQL? Or is MySQL OK for what I am doing?

Thank you!

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the nature of the data.

Comment: Ok so the data would contain a user ID and amount of money in account. The amount of money would get changed a lot in a short amount of time.

Comment: @AlecK.: This is impossible to answer.  Period.  You need to run experiments to see what level of load -- with your hardware, OS, data and software -- leads to what level of performance.  There's no way to determine throughput given a description.  The **only** way to determine throughput is with actual experiments using realistic data sizes and transaction volumes.

Comment: @S.Lott I get it, but seeing the things web hosts gave made me question it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql have [sysvar_max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) system parameter that is handling this.

Comment: So the max number of people at a time is 100,000. Am I correct?

Comment: 100,000 simultaneous database connections. If you don't use permanent connection, then the number will be approx the same as mysql queryies connections.

Comment: I understand the first part, but what do you mean permanent connection? Are you saying that the query runs constantly and never stops?

Comment: @Alec K.  What do you mean by "people at a time"?  Typically, only part of that "time" is spent in the database and the "time" they are actually connected to your server is pretty short.  If you are pooling/sharing database connections and you are accurately reflecting your true expected concurrent *active* sessions, you'll probably find that even 100 or 200 pooled connections to the database is sufficient and will support a much larger number of concurrent active http sessions.  Again, this all depends strongly the design of your application and, to a lesser extent, your hardware.

Comment: @gfortune I meant 100,000 connections are active at a single point in time.

Comment: 100,000 database connections? Why?  You're not being realistic about expected load or the hardware that you have available.  If you're talking about having 100,000 people looking at your website at one "time" (they might load 1-2 pages over one minute with a low cost query each or maybe even some cached results), then that's plenty doable and certainly doesn't require 100,000 database connections.  It also implies that you have an incredibly active userbase of several hundred thousand or millions of semi-active users.

Comment: @gfortune I am not talking about being realistic, the reason I said that was because of the 100,000 number I had seen. I am not thinking about whatever I plan on doing in general will have 100,000.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum load is going to vary based on the design of your application and the power of the hardware that you put it on.  A well designed application on reasonable hardware will far outperform what you need to get the project off the ground.

If you are unexpectedly successful, you will have money to put into real designers, real programmers and a real business plan.  Until then, just have fun hacking away and see if you can bring your idea to reality.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. I would just see webhosts saying "10 queries/sec" or "100 queries/sec", so I just wanted to know if it was limited or not. Thanks!

Comment: webhosts that are giving a metric like that with no context are suspect at best.  If a particular query is trying to compute the first million digits of pi and another query is finding the most recent 10 rows in a table indexed by the date, I can promise you the resources needed by the two queries is going to be drastically different.  Can the webhost calculate pi to a million digits 10 times per second?

Comment: I doubt it can. In fact it can't. Correct? Too much to get done in that amount of time.

Comment: @AlecK. "I just wanted to know if it was limited or not"?  Why ask us?  We're not your hosting company.  You should consider asking them.

Comment: @Alec K.  Right, it can't.  The point I'm making is that a "query" can be highly complex or very simple.  10 "queries" per second is an insanely inaccurate metric and not one that can be relied on for any useful analysis or comparison.

Comment: @S.Lott I'm not talking about the host, I'm talking about MySQL itself.